# Ошибка при регистрации

Tags: yii2

Люди помогите пожалуйста, при регистрации появляется:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'finance.users' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username`='sveta')

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 1146
    [2] => Table 'finance.users' doesn't exist
)
```

Смысл понятен что таблицы не существует, но как она может не существовать, если она есть, или я не так поняла что-то..

Comment: Кто нибудь с этим сталкивался?

Comment: многие сталкивались и причина во всех 100% случаев была одна и та же - таблицы не существовало в той БД к которой произведено подключение. тут без вариантов. Убедитесь что таблица у вас действительно на этом сервере, действительно в БД finance и что названа она именно маленькими буквами, а так же, что у подключающегося пользователя есть права на чтение этой таблицы

Comment: @Mike Спасибо сейчас ещё раз хорошенько пересмотрю